# Error in TinyXml++ tutorial

Tags: c++, tinyxml++

trying to compile the TinyXml++ [tutorial](https://ticpp.googlecode.com/svn/docs/ticpp.html) with CodeBlocks (16.01) and with VS2013 I get the same error at following line:

```
ticpp::Element* pElem = doc.FirstChildElement()->NextSibling();
```

CodeBlocks error:

> invalid conversion from 'ticpp::Node*' to 'ticpp::Element*'
>   [-fpermissive]

VS2013 error:

> cannot convert from 'ticpp::Node *' to 'ticpp::Element *'

Any idea?

Comment: That's not really a question, but it wouldn't be the first time an example is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In case you still want to compile it, regardless of whether there is an error in the tutorial, you can use the **auto** keyword for variable declaration.

For example:

```
auto pElem = doc.FirstChildElement()->NextSibling();
```

This way, the compiler will deduce the variable type at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `NextSibling()` is `Node*`.  If you want `Element*` as return type, you can use `NextSiblingElement()` instead.